# mutliple pdf generation with mpdf, display utf-8 charset,

Tags: php, codeigniter, utf-8, mpdf, persian

My project should generate multiple forms as pdf, I am using mpdf library with codeigniter framework. I test this code with english language it works fine. However I should create forms with persian language. The first form is created without any problem but the others are not displaying well the characters(as in picture). Please help me, I tried my best and searched a lot but could not find any solution for my issue.
This is the correct one[image]

all of the remaining pdfs without the first pdf have this problem[image]

```
require('my_controller.php');
$file_c = new File_Controller();
$file_c->create_file(/*parameters here*/);//creates one pdf file
$file_c->mfiles(/*parameters*/);//create more than one pdf file
```

because it is required to create the original file separately I use multiple forms.

I set the charset and direction to the html code. the following is the code that I used to generate pdf.

```
$this->load->library('m_pdf');
$mpdf=new mPDF('utf-8');
$mpdf=new mPDF('ar','A4','','',32,25,27,25,16,13);
$mpdf->debug = true;
$mpdf->SetDirectionality('rtl');
$mpdf->mirrorMargins = true;
$mpdf->WriteHTML($MyhtmlCode );
$mpdf->Output($thepath, "F");
```

The first pdf after creation should be opened in the browser. When I open it in windows (internet explorer or firefox) the pdf file can not open. but in mac it can be open in a browser.

```
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));
echo read_file($file);
```

(I used the same syntax and code for all pdfs and functions.)

Comment: Why you don't use `Download helper`?

Comment: thank you. the project should create multiple pdfs with utf-8 and just store them. I is not necessary to download them. Do you think download helper would help me ?

Comment: Same issue happens for me too. I was generating pdf in malayalam language.The first pdf , fonts are coming very fine, from second one onwards, they are distorted.I haven't cleared the issue yet, but if you are creating pdf for printing purpose, try to do it as a single long pdf and it will come out well.If your requirement is different, I don't have a solution yet .

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same issue. Finally, downgrading from mPDF **v6** to mPDF **v5** solved the it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the **mode** on object creation

```
$mpdf = new Mpdf(['mode' => 'UTF-8']);
```

if you are sure that your html is utf-8

p.s. it looks like you are creating the object 2 times.